# How one does an app detect wheteher another app is installed and signed up by the user in their phone?

Tags: android, authentication, ads

There are many android apps promoting other apps and gives rewards for installing the apps.So actually how , in android it is done - that in an app we can check the user's android pone if the targeted app is installed or not and **even more than that they check whether an user is signed up for that app or not** and then they give the rewards  once they find out that the other app is installed and signed up by user..(I am obviously not talking about launching intent to open the app which easilyb detects wheteher the app is installed or open play store).

Thanks in advance for help..

Answer (score 0):

Check if application is installed with packagename
Ask Question
Try this:

```
private boolean isPackageInstalled(String packagename, PackageManager packageManager) {
    try {
        packageManager.getPackageInfo(packagename, 0);
        return true;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It attempts to fetch information about the package whose name you passed in. Failing that, if a NameNotFoundException was thrown, it means that no package with that name is installed, so we return false.

Note that we pass in a PackageManager instead of a Context, so that the method is slightly more flexibly usable and doesn't violate the law of Demeter. You can use the method without access to a Context instance, as long as you have a PackageManager instance.

```
public void someMethod() {
    // ...

    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    boolean isInstalled = isPackageInstalled("com.somepackage.name", pm);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: But my question is not only to check if the app is installed - I can do that but the real issue is -HOW TO CHECK IF A USER IS SIGNED UP IN THE APP @pro titanic